# Вывод номера строки таблицы в запросе

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, запрос

Имеется 4 таблицы. В таблице Country нет числового id. Country Code - ключ типа Char.
 [image: Схема и пример запроса в Visual Studio]

Необходимо каждой строке таблицы Country в запросе присвоить числовое значение, чтобы в итоге выполнения запроса получались следующая выборка:
FirstName LastName CounryName CountryRowNumber
Новиков   Василий Russia      1
Иванов    Сергей  Russia      1
Jonh      Smith   USA         2
Ann       Smith   USA         2
Дополнительные колонки в БД создавать нельзя!

Comment: Скажите, это ведь просто задачка, да? это ведь не будет использоваться в реальном проекте?..

Comment: Если это просто учебная задачка - можете попробовать приспособить это [чудище](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/28184/) к вашей задаче. Если же это реальный проект - найдите способ всё же создать колонку.